# Как правильно сверстать этот элемент?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как валидно, правильно и оптимизировано это сверстать?

```css
.mail {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 2em;
  background-image: url('https://p1.hiclipart.com/preview/416/697/141/email-symbol-voicemail-letter-k9-mail-line-png-clipart-thumbnail.jpg');
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<a class="mail" href="malito:studio@yandex.ru">
  studio@yandex.ru
</a>
```

```css
.mail {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.mail__img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<a class="mail" href="malito:studio@yandex.ru">
  <img class="mail__img" src="https://p1.hiclipart.com/preview/416/697/141/email-symbol-voicemail-letter-k9-mail-line-png-clipart-thumbnail.jpg" alt=""> studio@yandex.ru
</a>
```

Спасибо

Comment: о чем конкретно вопрос? где найти такую картинку и какой шрифт поставить, или что не так с вашими попытками?

Comment: `line-height` выставить можно в высоту картинки, если вы решаете проблему с центрированием по высоте

Comment: По валидности явно выигрывает второй способ. Оба варианта одинаково правильные. Об оптимизации в таких задачах можно не думать

Comment: По валидности выигрывает второй, потому что значки и иконки относятся к контенту страницы, а не к фону

Comment: Спасибо! А почему об оптимизации не надо думать, незначительна?